# SQL Return results if one row is not null but still get the other results in that group that are null

Tags: sql

I have a query that finds returns results by person but i'm looking to get the results where one of the columns is not null but i still want to see all the other related rows

```
select person, hiredate, status, mtktype, startdate, enddate, supervisor, termdate, personpercentage
from employees 
left join mtkper on person = mtkperson
left join timekeep a on mtkperson = a.tkinit
left join timekeep b on supervisor = b.tkinit
where status <> 'TE'
and mtkdate2 > dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 0,0)
and person = 'sally'
order by person, status
```

Returns

But i simply cant do where termdate is not null because then i wont get the other three rows?

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and qualify the column names so it is clear where the columns are coming from.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: [Sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses window functions to count the number of non-NULL values:

```
select x.*
from (select person, hiredate, status, mtktype, startdate, enddate,
             supervisor, termdate, personpercentage,
             count(termdate) over (partition by person) as cnt_termdate
      from employees e left join
           mtkper p
           on person = mtkperson left join
           timekeep tkp
           on mtkperson = tkp.tkinit left join
           timekeep tks
           on supervisor = tks.tkinit
      where status <> 'TE' and
            mtkdate2 > convert(date, getdate()) and
            person = 'sally'
     ) x
where cnt_person > 0
order by person, status;
```

I introduced meaningful table aliases.  There may be other solutions, but without knowing where the columns comes from, it is hard to make suggestions.

Comment: that seems to work, thanks! How is it only pulling records where there is a term date? Because if there is no term date there is no count?

Comment: @BillK862 . . . `COUNT(<expression>)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  Hence, if all all values are `NULL`, it will return `0`, which gets filtered out.